# how to use Flask to save both uploaded file and user text input in json

Tags: python, flask

in html, I have

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
  <input type="number" name="speed " id="speed">
  <input type="file" id="stl_file">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I would like to save the value for speed in json file and save the uploaded stl file as well.

What I did in my app.py is

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,flash, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os 
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'stl','STL'}

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/' , methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        results =request.form
        file = request.files['stl_file']
        with open('file.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(results, f)
            
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(filename)
            return redirect(url_for('index')) 
        
        return render_template('main.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':

   app.run()
```

I can run it and I see my main page. However, when I input a number into speed, upload a file, and click submit, I get

```
Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Any suggestion on that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the name attribute of file.

```
<input type="file" name="stl_file" id="stl_file">
```